# How does large text file viewer work? How to build a large text reader

Tags: c++, python, qt, multithreading, pyqt

how does [large text file viewer work](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html)?

I'm assuming that:

- Threading is used to handle the file
- The TextBox is updated line by line
- Effective memory handling is used

Are these assumptions correct? if someone were to develop their own, what are the mustsand don'ts?

I'm looking to implement one using a DataGrid instead of a TextBox

I'm comfortable with C++ and python. I'll probably use QT/PyQT

**EDIT**

The files, I have are usually between 1.5 to 2 GB. I'm looking at editing and viewing these files

Comment: Do you need to edit or only read? When you way large text, how large do you mean (MB? GB?)?

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas 1 - 2 GB

Comment: Have you considered using a database to hold your data (since it is apparently in a grid form factor)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the trick is not loading the entire file into memory, but using seek and such to just load the part which is viewed (possibly with a block before and after to handle a bit of scrolling). Perhaps even using memory-mapped buffers, though I have no experience with those.

Do realize that **modifying** a large file (fast) is different from just viewing it. You might need to copy the gigabytes of data surrounding the edit to a new file, which may be slow.

Answer (score 4):

In Kernighan and Plaugher's classic (antique?) book "Software Tools in Pascal" they cover the development and design choices of a version of ed(1) and note

> "A warning: `edit` is a big
>   program (excluding contributions from
>   `translit`, `find`, and `change`; at
>   950 lines, it is fifty percent bigger
>   than anything else in this book."

And they (literally) didn't even have string types to use. Since they note that the file to be edited may exist on [tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_729) which doesn't support arbitrary writes in the middle, they had to keep an index of line positions in memory and work with a scratch file to store changes, deletions and additions, merging the whole together upon a "save" command. They, like you, were concerned about memory constraining the size of their editable file.

The general structure of this approach is preserved in the [GNU ed project](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ed), particularly in `buffer.c`

Comment: I know that you can overwrite data in a file (on disk), but inserts in a file are also on disk not supported I think.

Comment: It is of historical interest only, but since you asked... You are correct, most disk file systems will let you *overwrite* stuff in the middle of a file but not insert. Because of the mechanics of some tape encodings, writing in the middle doesn't overwrite the data there, it borks the entire file.